# Value doesn't parse into my object during the deserialization of JSON C#

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am currently working on program that proceses data that i get from api. But i can't find a way to de-serialize objects after the items list. I am using Newtonsoft.JsonConvert for the job.

Code for testing

```
    struct Next
    {
        string href { get; set; }
    }
     public struct MetaInfo
    {
        int totalCount { get; set; }
        public List<Order> items { get; set; }
        Next next { get; set; }
        int pageCount { get; set; }
     }
    public class Orders
    {

       public List<Order> items { get; set; }

        public Orders()
        {
            items = new List<Order>();
        }
    }
  public  class Order 
    {

        public bool buy { get; set; }
        public   DateTime issued { get; set; }
    public   decimal price { get; set; }
    public   int volume { get; set; }
    public   int duration { get; set; }
    public   ulong id { get; set; }
    public   int minVolume { get; set; }
    public  string range { get; set; }
    public   ulong stationID { get; set; }
    public   int type { get; set; }



        public Order(bool buy, DateTime issued,decimal price,int volume,int duration,ulong id, int minVolume,string range,ulong stationID,int type)
        {
            this.buy = buy;
            this.issued = issued;
            this.price = price;
            this.volume = volume;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.id = id;
            this.minVolume = minVolume;
            this.range = range;
            this.stationID = stationID;
            this.type = type;

        }

    }
}
```

Sample of data i am trying to deserialize:

```
{"items": [{"buy": false, "issued": "2017-03-07T11:06:09", "price": 50000.0, "volume": 1, "duration": 365, "id": 911203054, "minVolume": 1, "volumeEntered": 1, "range": "region", "stationID": 60000274, "type": 967}, {"buy": false, "issued": "2017-03-28T11:23:16", "price": 50000.0, "volume": 1, "duration": 365, "id": 911203055, "minVolume": 1, "volumeEntered": 1, "range": "region", "stationID": 60000277, "type": 967}], "totalCount": 280705, "previous": {"href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/10000002/orders/all/"}, "next": {"href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/10000002/orders/all/?page=3"}, "pageCount": 10}
```

Comment: what exactly is going wrong? It's not clear what the problem is

Comment: Just copy your JSON string and paste it by going to Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes in Visual Studio and use the RootObject in deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upon a time, I got stuck in the same kind of problem.

and then I found this tool: [this](http://json2csharp.com/)

use these classes

```
public class Item
{
    public bool buy { get; set; }
    public string issued { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int minVolume { get; set; }
    public int volumeEntered { get; set; }
    public string range { get; set; }
    public int stationID { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
}

public class Previous
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Next
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
    public Previous previous { get; set; }
    public Next next { get; set; }
    public int pageCount { get; set; }
}
```

Happy coding :)